# How to use Loop and Assign in Flows to clone permission sets?

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

I have been working on a project to clone an existing user to create a new user. I need to be able to pull all the information from the existing user's record, including permission sets. I have a basic flow created that functions like this:

1. Screen prompts user to enter the email address of the user to clone
2. Record Lookup element finds the user record based on matching email address and pulls configurations (role/profile, is Marketing User checked?, etc.)
3. Another record lookup takes the userid and looks for permission sets
4. A screen prompts collection of info for new user (Name, email, etc.)
5. a record lookup gets managerid based on manager's email address entered in step 4
6. Record Create element to create the new user
7. Another record create element to add permission sets found in step 3

[image: ScreenshotofFLow]

I am extremely inexperienced with flows and I am trying to learn as I go, but I am pretty sure that I am NOT going about this the right way. The flow is working, in terms of finding the user to mirror, and is pulling some info like role/profile and creates a new user, but it is not pulling all of the information needed. The most pressing questions I have now are:

1. What is the most efficient/proper way to accomplish this?
2. How do I pull all permissionSetIds assigned to the user being mirrored so that I can assign them to the new user?
3. How do I configure variables for checkbox fields to carry over? (Marketing User, Service Cloud User, etc.)? I have variables created but I've noticed when testing the boxes aren't being checked on the new records.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Flows are not "expressive" enough to adequately perform this task, and even if it were, I strongly suspect it would take you less time to *learn* Visualforce and Apex Code *and* hack together a solution that way. Flows are notoriously hard to work with, and even harder to debug.

Comment: Off of the top of my head, I'd guess this is going to be something like a 14 step Flow, minimum, more if you want to copy feature licenses and other stuff as well.

Comment: I am trying to learn VF and Apex Code, but I don't think it's going to happen fast enough. I don't mind a 14 step Flow lol. What I'm really asking is how to configure a Loop element to capture multiple record Ids for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this can be done with a flow, and it will be faster to learn a flow than trying to create test classes.

I believe you are trying to Lookup the `PermissionSet` object when you really need the `PermissionSetAssignment` object. (because User to Permission Set is a Many-to-Many relationship, it needs a Join object between them)

After lookup the original `User`, then Fast Lookup the `PermissionSetAssignment` object with the criteria:

```
AssigneeId = OriginalUserIDVariable
```

(Fast Lookup returns a collection rather than a single record.  But it's not fast)

Save the `PermissionSetId` 's in a collection variable, and then Loop through that variable to populate a an sObject Collection variable of sObject `PermissionSetAssignment` for the newly created User.

Comment: Hey Brian, I am able to pull the userid and set AssigneeId = varuserId, however, I am not understanding how to pull and save multiple permission sets to assign to the new user. When you say "Save the PermissionSetIds in a collection variable, am I to enter the values of the permission sets in the system?

Comment: I'm so confused with this Loop and sObject collection stuff. I can get it to pull multiple permission set Ids, but I can't figure out to store them all/assign them so that later in the process I can assign those values to a new user record.

Comment: See sample of a loop and collection variable here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_example_collvar.htm&type=5